# ceph health command returns a failure

Tags: cluster-computing, centos7, ceph

i'm new to ceph but have to build a mini-cluster as part of a project, i have been following an online tutorial of how to build one and all was fine until i restarted my machines the following day. now when i perform the command ceph health it returns an error saying: 2015-01-08 15:35:04.037375 7fae717fa700  0 -- :/1003525 >> 192.168.1.12:6789/0 pipe(0x7fae6c000c00 sd=3 :0 s=1 pgs=0 cs=0 l=1 c=0x7fae6c000e90).fault.

and whenever i run the same command on the 192.168.1.12 machine it returns an error saying: monclient(hunting): ERROR: missing keyring, cannot use cephx for authentication.
0 librados: client.admin initialization error (2) No such file or directory. Error connecting to cluster: ObjectNotFound.

I have been searching the internet for a while now for any answers and not found much, i noticed this site tends to be good in answering most if not all questions though, so any help would be greatly appreciated thanks. Im using centos 7 on all machines if thats any help.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a programming question as defined in the [help] guidelines.

Comment: This should probably be moved to server fault or something.

Answer (score 9):

Check if you have the permission to read the keyring file in

`/etc/ceph/ceph.client.admin.keyring`

If this file is not readable by your user, or it is missing, you are not able to do

`ceph -w`

If the keyring is missing you can install the keyring from the admin node using `ceph-deploy admin serverhostname`

Comment: Thanks a lot!  I was trying to exercise Ceph on an OpenStack cluster freshly deployed through Mirantis Fuel (5.1.1).  I stubbornly refused to use root to do my testing and your post guided me to the problem: `/etc/ceph/ceph.client.admin.keyring` was 500.  I'm unsure (yet) of the consequence of widening the permissions to that file so I have taken a copy of `/etc/ceph/ceph.conf` into my home dir and added a `keyring` entry under `[global]` to point it to a readable copy.  Finally use `-c ~/ceph.conf` to point the commands to my own copy, as in: `ceph status -c ~/ceph.conf`

Answer (score 1):

As the error saying:  ERROR: missing keyring. That means you don't have the keyring file.

Beside, this error, 
error saying: 2015-01-08 15:35:04.037375 7fae717fa700 0 -- :/1003525 >> 192.168.1.12:6789/0 pipe(0x7fae6c000c00 sd=3 :0 s=1 pgs=0 cs=0 l=1 c=0x7fae6c000e90).fault.

It means your monitor didn't start up cause you missing the keyring file.

Step to resolve this problem:
1. Check the monitor host, and let it start up.
2. Execute the command "ceph -s" on monitor to check this cluster.